# How to add generated projet in the TFS2010 Binaries output folder

Tags: build-automation

With TFS2010 build, the build of a solution with web projects creates a "_PublishedWebsites" in the Binaries output folder and delete all Bin folders in the Sources folder. So impossible to move by script another generated project.

How can I move another generated projets no web in the same solution to the Binaries folder ? Because, in my solution, I have a web project, a Service Web project and a console project. Only the Console project is not move in the Binaries folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your solution by creating a solution with a web project (MVC 3), windows service, and console application.  At first everything built and then I changed the platform to "Any CPU".  I noticed by default the windows service and console applications only have x86 platform. When I ran the build with the Any CPU platform, it only built the web application.

Did you select "Any CPU" for the build definition?  If so, that might be the reason it skipped that project.  If you go to Build > Configuration Manager, you can see what configurations/platforms are available.  You can update the build defintion to build both by leaving the platform blank.

Let me know if this is or isn't the case and if there is anything else I can try to recreate.

Mike

Comment: I tried to build with platform blank. My console application is well moved in Binaries, but all files are mixed with files of others projects ! How can I move all files in a sub folder Binaries\MyConsoleApp ?

Comment: It requires some customization, but you can break it up into the folders. Here is an article on it.  http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/31/Customizable+Output+Directories+For+TFS+2010+Build.aspx

Comment: Did you try this solution for breaking out the binaries in their project folders?